# Is there a way to open an app without a launcher using firebase dynamic Iink?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm currently creating a video player plugin app for my streaming website. This is because most browser don't support some codecs. The app don't have to show in the launcher category so I add this xml code to get rid of launcher icon.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="streameo.page.link"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

But when I integrate Firebase dynamic link, it's not opening app, but after adding the launcher category back it's working. Is there a work around?

Answer (score 1):

In general, one intent filter has nothing to do with any other intent filter. That server does not respond with a [`.well-known/assetlinks.json`](https://streameo.page.link/.well-known/assetlinks.json) - which means, that `autoVerify="true"` will fail. Consult the logcat output; it should complain about the failed verification.

One can check such `.well-known/assetlinks.json` with [`digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com`](https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://streameo.page.link&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls).
When hosting a proper `.well-known/assetlinks.json` there, the response should look different:

```
{
  "maxAge": "600s",
  "debugString": "********************* ERRORS *********************\n
                  None!\n
                  ********************* INFO MESSAGES *********************\n
                  * Info: No statements were found that match your query\n"
}
```

The [Statement List Generator and Tester](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator) can be used to generate such an `assetlinks.json`.

---

One can also setup the `<activity />` for implicit deep-linking:

```
<nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_graph"/>
```

Then use [`FragmentActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity) to [handle the deep link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#handle) `Intent` with Navigation component.
Also see [create an explicit deep link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit). It's not so difficult when Navigation is set up already.

Comment: I remove autoVerify from intent-filter still can't open app, since their is no category.launcher in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: The problem is not firebase-dynamic link not working, but app not opening when no category.launcher declared in activity.

Comment: Without auto-verify this link is not verified either - and I never claimed that. Try adding `android.intent.action.MAIN` instead; `LAUNCHER` is not required to start an `Activity`. You're ignoring the problem - and the question doesn't show logcat proof that the link validates.

Comment: Problem now is that I can't get link in activity. it's returning null .